# D3.js Applying update pattern to pie chart

Tags: d3.js, updates, pie-chart

I am trying to get an update pattern to work on a pie chart using d3.js v4. The data changes when selected from a dropdown menu.

Mainly I would like to be able to use the correct update pattern so that I can .exit() .enter() and update the data. Also I would like to be able to use the arcTween() function he uses from one of Bostock's examples.

I am trying to implement [this example by HarryStevens on b.locks](https://bl.ocks.org/lorenzopub/3003e3fc845b47dda25a26b35ca40b4b).

Currently I am getting the following error,

> pie is not a function

from line 140, which reads,

```
  .data(pie(category_count),
```

and is marked in the code below with asterixs.

This is part of the code,

```
// Generate an array object on categories as a category
        var category_count = d3.nest()
          .key(function(d) {
            return d.category;
          })
          .rollup(function(leaves) {
            return leaves.length;
          })
          .entries(data);
        // console.log(category_count);

        var pie = d3.pie()
          .padAngle(.02)
          .sort(null)
          .value(function(d) {
            return d.value;
          })
          (category_count);

        function arcTween(a) {
          console.log(this._current);
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) {
            return arc(i(t));
          };
        }

        var arc = d3.arc()
          .outerRadius(radius - 10)
          .innerRadius(radius / 2);

        var labelArc = d3.arc()
          .outerRadius(radius - 10)
          .innerRadius(radius - 100);

        var svgPie = d3.select("#pie")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + radius) + "," + (margin.top + radius) + ")"); //center of pie

        var arcs = svgPie.selectAll("arc")
   ******** .data(pie(category_count), ******** 
            function(d) {
              return d.data.key
            });

        arcs
          .transition()
          .duration(4000)
          .attrTween("d", arcTween);

        // EXIT old elements not present in new data
        arcs.enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("class", "arc exit")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return color[i];
          })
          .attr("d", arc)
          .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
          });
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Pie-Chart-Update-Pattern) on github.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is `category_count` applied to the function when it's declared? I'm not sure that returns an actual function.

Comment: Yes what @RyanMorton said! You are setting pie to the return of the d3.pie()(category_count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently setting `pie` to the return of the function `d3.pie()(category_count)`. `d3.pie()` itself returns a function. So what you would want to do is this:

```
var pie = d3.pie()
      .padAngle(.02)
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });
```

Then when you call it like this:

```
var arcs = svgPie.selectAll("arc")
   .data(pie(category_count),
        function(d) {
          return d.data.key
        });
```

This is now invoking the function `pie` with the arguments `category_count`.

Comment: Brilliant that fixed it, thanks a lot. I wonder why the arcTween is not working. Check it out https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-v4-Pie-Chart-Update-Pattern/#